# Storing datatable content in PHP session

Tags: php, html

So have a datatable wherein if i click a cell, it redirects me to another page. The problem is I need to store the clicked data for the next page. I wanted to store /tablez.cell(this).data()/ inside a session but I'm not sure if it's possible. Here's my code so far:

```
var tablez= $('#table').DataTable();
    $('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
            console.log(tablez.cell(this).data());
             window.location.href = "FH_Suppliers_Add.php";
     });
```

Comment: You can only send data by two ways. First is query string as @justbaron did a comment and Second way is using Ajax.

Comment: what do you by query string?

Comment: You can also use Local Storage or cookies.

Comment: [Use GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Query string means to send variable with GET Request. Like this way:
`var tablez= $('#table').DataTable();
    $('#table tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
            var data = tablez.cell(this).data();
             window.location.href = "FH_Suppliers_Add.php?var=data";
     });`
and on PHP page you will get this by using $_GET['var']

Comment: I tried the code but i keep on getting an error 404 not foud. is it because i inserted the ?var=data?